# HQL Exception (org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect$3)

Tags: hql

I am trying to execute the following HQL query from java.

"SELECT ac.accountNumberInt, ag.ext, sum (ext) as exta from CustomerCapital ag, Account ac where customerExt =:customerExt and observationPeriod in (:observationPeriod) group by ac.accountNumberInt, ag.ext";

It is throwing the following exception.

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect$3.getReturnType(Dialect.java:125) ~[hibernate-core.jar!/:3.3.1.GA]
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findFunctionReturnType(SessionFactoryHelper.java:405) ~[hibernate-core.jar!/:3.3.1.GA]

Can anyone please guide me on this.

Comment: Have you tried fixing the query (remove the extra comma before the from clause, using ag.ext instead of ag.Ext, and specifying the entity alias before the properties)? If it still doesn't work, have you tried a more recent version of Hibernate? 3.3.1 is old.

Comment: comma and ag.Ext came by mistake while copying.

Answer (score 0):

ag.ext cannot be in the group by and also in an aggregate function.
Prehapse you ment sum(ac.ext) if so you need to point it out with the Class alias

```
you can't have ambiguous fields :     sum (ext) ==> sum (ac/ag.ext)
                                      observationPeriod  ==> ac/ag.observationPeriod
                                      customerExt ==> ac/ag.customerExt
```